# Domain and sign of an integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have a question on the domain and the sign of an integral. The integral is $$f\left(x\right)=\left(\int _{-1}^x\frac{\arctan \left(3t\right)}{t}dt\:\right) $$
I have no idea how to solve it. Thanks for any possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

$f(-1)=0$ and $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}\arctan(3x)$ by the fundamental theorem. This expression is positive for all $x\in\mathbb R$, så $f$ is monotonically increasing. Can you conclude from here?

Comment: How did you solved the integral $ f\left(x\right)=\left(\int _{-1}^x\frac{\arctan \left(3t\right)}{t}dt\:\right) $ I can't find a way to solve it. Neither by substitution nor by parts.

Comment: @T4yl0r The trick is that he did not "solve it" (which, depending on your familiarity with the polylogarithm function, might have been more or less enlightening). Fact is that he did not need to do it.

Comment: How did you draw the conclusion that the espression is positive for all x?

Comment: We know that arctan is positive for positive arguments, and odd. Thus, dividing by $x$ we get positivity for all $x\neq0$. (At zero the limit is positive (equal to 3).)